# Sending email using email.mime.multipart in Python

Tags: python, email, mime-types

I'm trying to learn python from a book ("Hello! Python"). This code should, according to the book, send an email.  no luck so far.

```
import os

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

def send_message(message):
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.me.com')
    s.sendmail(message['From'], message['To'], message.as_string())
    s.quit()

def mail_report(to, ticker_name):
    outer = MIMEMultipart()
    outer['Subject'] = "Stock report for " + ticker_name
    outer['From'] = "myemail@mac.com"
    outer['To'] = to

    # Internal text container
    inner = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    text = "Here is the stock report for " + ticker_name
    html = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>Here is teh stock report for
          <b> """ + ticker_name + """ </b>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    inner.attach(part1)
    inner.attach(part2)
    outer.attach(inner)

    filename = 'stocktracker-%s.csv' % ticker_name
    csv_text = ''.join(file(filename).readlines())
    csv_part = MIMEText(csv_text, 'csv')
    csv_part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename), outer.attach(csv_part)
    return outer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email = mail_report('myemail@mac.com', 'GOOG')
    send_message(email)
```

I don't get an error, but I also don't get an email.  (needless to say, i'm using my actual email, not 'myemail@mac.com')  All suggestions and suggested reading appreciated.

Comment: If you want to send an email suing somebody you should seek legal advice :-)

Comment: i don't mean to be thick, but i don't get it.  Do i have some stupid typo in there?

Comment: @dwstein: Fixed that for ya. :-) (spot the difference in the [post revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12307485/revisions))

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I'm an idiot! Fair enough.  But, can you help with the code?

Comment: @dwstein: not getting an error means this is not necessarily a python problem. You can print the email in all it's glory for testing with `print(email.as_string())` to see if there is anything obviously wrong, but it could be that the receiving SMTP server is discarding it silently as spam, for example.

Comment: You nailed it!  the emails were in my spam folder.  It's odd because I did a simpler email test using MIMEText, as opposed to MIMEMultipart, and the email went right through to my inbox.  Why would these go to my spam?   Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Because it's repeatedly the same message, i.e. spam.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a local smtp debugging server.  Find where smtpd.py is located, then run the command:

```
$ python /usr/lib/python2.7/smtpd.py -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:8025
```

Then on a second terminal screen run the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 8025)
>>> s.sendmail('me', 'you', 'Hi!')
```

You should see 'Hi!' in the first screen.

Comment: I tried the second way and got the following error: `socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

Comment: @dwstein:  What do you mean, the second way?  You run the smtp debugging server in one terminal, then run the Python client code in another.

Answer (score 0):

[smtplib.sendmail](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) should eventually raise an exception if it can't send the mail - it may just take a while for the timeout due to the connection being dropped by a firewall. Give it a few minutes. Meanwhile, read below about what could be going wrong.

The code tries to directly connect to **smtp.me.com** and send mail via SMTP (port 25). This will only work if:

- Your internet setup lets you make outgoing connections on port 25
- smtp.me.com listens on port 25 (it does)
- the recipient email is a valid address ending in **@mac.com** (**myemail@mac.com** is not valid: `550 5.1.1 unknown or illegal alias: myemail@mac.com`
  )
- smtp.me.com still processes emails for @mac.com (Mobile Me was shut down in favor of iCloud some time ago, so I'm not sure the @mac.com addresses are still valid)

You can substitute any other mail server for **smtp.me.com**, preferably that of your ISP, which should be willing to relay email to any address (unlike smtp.me.com, which will only care about the mac.com domain).

Comment: Thanks!  I tried the mail server for road-runner (smtp-server.nyc.rr.com) and got an error saying I needed authentication.  Not sure why.  the smtp.me.com server ended up working and my mac account is still being supported.